# Has a Multitape Machine like this been Studied?

Tags: turing-machines, computability

Sometimes as a hobby I like to think about different possible "fundamental" abstract computing frameworks, akin for instance to Turing Machines and Lambda Calculus. In particular, I've been interested in conceptions in which a small set of 0-argument functions themselves comprise the input/output/alphabet. I ended up thinking about something similar to a [Multitape Turing Machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitape_Turing_machine). Actually it can easily be defined as a particular Multitape Turing Machine if a tape pointer can stay put following a transition, but it is more easily conceptualized if presented a different way. It features the following:

- The alphabet $\Gamma = \{\textbf{>}, \textbf{+}, \textbf{!}, \textbf{|}\}$, explained below.
- A blank symbol $b$
- Two tapes **A** and **B** which extend infinitely in both directions, with respective contents $a_i, b_i \in \Gamma \cup \{b\}$ for every integer $i$. Call **A** the "active tape" and **B** the "passive tape". This machine is defined so that the tape pointers are always pointing to $a_0$ and $b_0$.
- Transitions which work like this:

  - If $a_0 = \textbf{>}$ ("Move"), shift the pointer for **B** right one, so $b_{i} := b_{i + 1}$ for every integer $i$
  - If $a_0 = \textbf{+}$ ("Successor"), increment $b_0$ modulo 4 as if $\textbf{>} = 0, \textbf{+} = 1, \textbf{!} = 2,$ and $\textbf{|} = 3$, and do nothing for the blank symbol. In other words,

  $b_0 := \left\{
      \begin{array}{}
          \textbf{+} & \text{if } b_0 = \textbf{>}\\
          \textbf{!} & \text{if } b_0 = \textbf{+}\\
          \textbf{|} & \text{if } b_0 = \textbf{!}\\
          \textbf{>} & \text{if } b_0 = \textbf{|}\\
          b & \text{if } b_0 = b\\
      \end{array}
  \right\}$

  - If $a_0 = \textbf{!}$ ("Reverse"), reverse the direction the tape pointer of **B** moves. Mathematically speaking, $b_i \leftrightarrow b_{-i}$ (by $\leftrightarrow$ I mean they are swapped) for every integer $i$.
  - If $a_0 = \textbf{|}$ ("Swap"), swap the active and passive tape. Mathematically speaking, $a_i \leftrightarrow b_i$ for every integer $i$.
  - If $a_0 = b$, the machine halts.

Additionally, **A** shifts right by one after reading each symbol, so $a_{i} := a_{i + 1}$ for every integer $i$ (note that for $\textbf{|}$ this means **A** is advanced *after* the swap).

Here are two examples, with $A_0$ and $B_0$ denoting the finite initial contents of **A** and **B** respectively:

1.
$A_0$ = `|>>>>>|`
$B_0$ = `||+++++!|+++++!|+++++|`
In this example, **B** is advanced to its last `|` while **A** is advanced to the blank symbol just after its last `|`, where the machine terminates.
2. $A_0$ = `>|!|`, $B_0$ = `|!|`. In this example, the machine loops infinitely.

I find this machine interesting, and so my question is simply this: has something similar to it or something it reduces to been studied before, and if so does it have any interesting properties? Is it universal? The first example suggests a mechanism for **A** and **B** to "work in tandem" to implement goto-like behavior, and I've been playing around with safely encoding bits on the tapes and implementing succession, it feels possible but fairly complicated. This is just something I'm curious about, I have no application in mind.